# Calculate total area of both adjacent and contiguous raster cells within a radial distance around a polygon's centroid

Tags: raster, r, area, nodata, equal-area

I have a raster containing grid-cell values of either `1` or no data, `NA`, representing used- or unused-habitat types, respectively.

Using R's `raster` package, I want to calculate the total area (in hectares) of a contiguous block of adjacent cells that fall within a defined (either square or circular) radial distance around a polygon's centroid.

My raster has a resolution of 30-m by 30-m (e.g., with a Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection), and each grid cell is approximately 90 square-meters in size. After counting the number of contiguous cells within a block, as defined by the radial distance around a centroid, I then multiply the total cell count by 90 (i.e. ignoring `NA` values) and later divide that product by 10,000 to convert from the total area in square-meters to the total area in hectares.

The problem that I am running into is that my usage of `raster::ncell` and `raster::clump` together returns the (grand total) number cells within a block, despite asking for no data, `NA`, values to be ignored. I also wanted the code to consider only the contiguous block of cells that is *immediately adjacent* to each polygon centroid within the defined radial distance. In other words, I did not want to quantify the total area based on other contiguous blocks separated from the immediately adjacent block by  the no data, `NA`, features.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
cropped_locale <- crop(x=raster, y=extent(subset(centroids, Locale=="Name"))+5000) ##Cropping raster 5000 m around one centroid
total_area <- (ncell(clump(cropped_locale, directions=8, na.rm=TRUE))*90)/10000 ##Converting from square-meters to hectares
```

And here's an image of a subset of the raster data, including one polygon's centroid:
[image: The black cross denotes a polygon's centroid while the gray (1) and white (no data) cells denote used-habitat and unused-habitat types, respectively. The boundaries of the raster image are defined by a radial distance from the centroid, forming a square around the location.]

Perhaps my usage of both the `ncell()` and `clump()` functions is an incorrect approach to such calculations, and I am open to any suggestions.